# How to create a new table from two different tables in sqlite3?

Tags: sqlite

I want to merge two tables to create a new one. My first database table `Data` has these kind of information:

```
cell_id i j

1       1 1
2       2 1 
3       3 1
4       4 1   
5       5 1  
6       1 2    
7       2 2     
8       3 2  
9       4 2        
10      5 2
```

Second table whose name is `Layer` is like that, it contains geometry as record:

```
geom

blob
blob
blob
blob
blob
```

I want to create a layer or insert into values in `Data` to the `Layer` where `j=1` (it means 5 rows in `Data` table same as `Layer` table row number). Like that:

```
cell_id i j geom

1       1 1 blob
2       2 1 blob
3       3 1 blob
4       4 1 blob   
5       5 1 blob
```

How can I handle it in sqlite3?

Comment: Other than `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT` exactly as the documentation tells you?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to [`CREATE VIEW`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html) maybe? That's might be a solution.

```
CREATE VIEW LayerData AS
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM Layer L
JOIN Data D
WHERE L.j = 1
```

Or, as stated by [Ignacio Vazquea-Abrams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20862/ignacio-vazquez-abrams), you can use [`CREATE TABLE ... AS`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html).